# Left Join Issue

Tags: mysql

Am trying to do a left join along with a condition. Say this is my table:

```
a     b     c
-------------------------
1     1     NULL
3     3     something
```

and my query is

```
select * from x left join y on x.a = y.b
```

The problem is that I don't want c to be "something" so when i add

```
select * from x left join y on x.a = y.b where y.c <> 'something'
```

it displays 0 rows. it should actually display

```
a     b     c
-------------------------
1     1     NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * 
from x left join y on x.a = y.b 
WHERE y.c IS NULL OR y.c <> 'something'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you ment:

```
SELECT *
FROM x
LEFT JOIN y ON x.a = y.b
WHERE y.c <> 'something'
```

Answer (score 0):

Old reply, but normally for this the easiest solution is to put the check in the ON clause:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM x 
LEFT OUTER JOIN y 
ONx.a = y.b 
AND y.c <> 'something'
```